# Filter function in Python (simple question)

Tags: python, filter

Can somebody explain to me why the following code produces an error:

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange"]
filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: x if x[0]=="A", fruit_lst)
```

I'm trying to print out the values which start with the letter A.

Comment: Because `x if x[0]=="A"` isn't a valid expression. What's the value if it's **not** equal to A? Probably you just wanted to return the condition itself to be used to filter the list.

Comment: A ternary expression requires an `else` clause.

Comment: "an error" - please be specific. The traceback message would help.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a syntax error because an `if` expression has to include `else`, there's no default value.

But you don't need `if` here. The callback function of `filter()` just needs to return a boolean, so just use the comparison.

```
filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('A'), fruit_lst)
```

Note that `filter()` is generally not considered pythonic, conditional list comprehensions are usually preferred.

```
filtered_lst = [x for x in fruit_lst if x.startswith('A')]
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` works by expecting `True` or `False` in order to keep the values in the list, so your way can be fixed to

```
filtered_lst = list(filter(lambda x: True if x[0]=="A" else False, fruit_lst))
```

However, its more correct to do it like this:

```
filtered_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x[0]=="A", fruit_lst))
```

Or

```
filtered_lst = [x for x in fruit_lst if x[0]=="A"]
```

Comment: I would argue that it is not "more correct" to do it like that, just a bit shorter and more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

You Have to add `else` in `inline` **if statement**

for example:

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange"]
filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: x if x[0]=="A" else 0, fruit_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incomplete. It can be corrected like this.

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange"]
filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: True if x[0]=="A" else False , fruit_lst)
for s in filtered_lst:
    print(s)
```

**Output**

```
Apple
Apricot
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct  `if x[0]=="A"` is not valid syntax. That's what the error tries to tell you.

The reason it is not valid is that you can not just return only sometimes from the lambda function. You'll have to define what it should return.

Having a look at the [filter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) we can see

> `filter(function, iterable)`
> Construct an iterator from those elements of `iterable` for which `function` returns true.

So what you want is to have a lambda function that returns either True or False, depending on whether the item should be kept.

```
 filter(lambda x: x[0]=="A", fruit_lst)
```

This does the trick. Note that it returns not a list, but a "filter object". If you want to have a list instead of an iterable (e.g. for debug printing), you will have to use `list()` on this.

---

By the way (just as a fun fact), if you wanted to use `if` somewhere in your code, you could also do this:

```
filtered_lst = [x for x in fruit_lst if x[0]=="A"]
```

Here, the `if` without `else` is allowed because it's a different syntactic construct. It says "take `x` if it fulfills this, and do not take it otherwise"

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The reason is that you need to provide the `else` statement in the `if ... else` structure. A solution would be to supply the `else` statement shown in the code snippet below:

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange"]
filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: x if x[0]=="A" else None, fruit_lst)
```

Also, if you would like to view the `filtered_lst` as a Python list, make sure to convert the `filter object` resulting from the `filter` operation to a list as follows:

```
filtered_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x if x[0]=="A" else None, fruit_lst))
```

If you were then to print out the list called `filtered_lst`, you'd get the desired result as follows:

```
['Apple', 'Apricot']
```

EDIT: Having read the previous answers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168448/11670378) one seems the most elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall), to find the elements in your list that start with "A":

```
import re
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange"]
filtered_lst = [s for s in fruit_lst if re.findall(r'^A', s)]
print(filtered_lst)
# ['Apple', 'Apricot']
```

Note that this method allows you to easily extend the code to other related functionalities, such as to find elements that start with "a" in case-insensitive way:

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange", "apple"]
filtered_lst = [s for s in fruit_lst if re.findall(r'^a', s, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(filtered_lst)
# ['Apple', 'Apricot', 'apple']
```

Or those that have "p" anywhere, case-insensitive:

```
fruit_lst = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Apricot", "Orange", "apple"]
filtered_lst = [s for s in fruit_lst if re.findall(r'p', s, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(filtered_lst)
# ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Apricot', 'apple']
```